# cli connection to oracle on linux

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect to a local oracle on both windows and linux machines.
I am running the following command

```
echo Select count(*) FROM all_tables where owner='schema_name'; | sqlplus USER/PASS@localhost:1521
```

It works on windows but I get a syntax error on Linux. Can someone please fine tune my command to run on Linux?

This is the error I get:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the query in quotes:

```
echo "Select count(*) FROM all_tables where owner='schema_name';" | sqlplus USER/PASS@localhost:1521
```